# How to send query parameters as part of URL in Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I would like to send a url with a few additional query parameters. In a nutshell, I would like to make a `GET` request with a structure similar to this:

```
https://www.example.com/api?command=<Get>&<partnerName>=<SAMPLE PARTNER NAME>&<authToken>=<AUTH TOKEN>&<returnValueList>=<TYPE OF RETURN>
```

Here is what I have on ajax:

```
function getReq(token){
    console.log('get Req triggered in JS')
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "proxy.php?url=https://www.example.com/api?command=Get"+"&"+"partnerName=test"+"&"+"authToken="+token+"&"+"returnValueList="+"transactionList",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        data: token,
        success: function (data){
            console.log('get success', data)
        }
    })
}
```

This is what I have in proxy.php:

```
function makeGetRequest($baseURL) {
    print_r('make Get Request triggered');
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $baseURL);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);  
    if($e = curl_error($ch)) {
        echo $e;
    } else {
      echo $response;
    }
}
```

The response I get indicates that I am not sending my query params correctly.

**UPDATE** I added the parameters to a data object:

```
function getReq(token){
    console.log('get Req triggered in JS')
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "proxy.php?url=https://www.example.com/api?command=Get",
        data: {partnerName: 'applicant', authToken: token, returnValueList: 'transactionList'},
        success: function (data){
            console.log('get success', data)
        }
    })
}
```

this is what I have in proxy.php now:

```
$fullURL = $baseURL+'&partnerName='+$_GET['partnerName']+'&authToken='+$_GET['authToken']+'&returnValueList='+$_GET['returnValueList'];
print_r($fullURL);
```

I am getting this error:

```
127.0.0.1:59256 [500]: GET /proxy.php?url=https://www.example.com/api?command=Get&partnerName=***&authToken=***&returnValueList=transactionList - Uncaught TypeError: Unsupported operand types: string + string
```

Comment: Put all the parameters in the `data:` object. jQuery will append them to the URL automatically.

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? Could it work better if you escaped the `&` in the URL properly, such that all parameters are seen as the parameters of the value of `url` instead of being parameters for `proxy.php`?

Comment: @Barmar I updated my question, I tried that, but getting a different error now

Comment: That you need to apply proper URL encoding in a situation like this, when introducing one URL into another as a parameter value, should be pretty obvious. Yet, not even an attempt with your first code there?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try passing the parameters by adding them to your ajax request like that:

```
data: { 
    firstParam: firstParamValue, 
    secondParam: secondParamValue, 
}
```

And removing them from url.

Get them after with PHP:

```
$firstParam = $_GET['firstParam'];
$secondParam = $_GET['secondParam'];
```

Comment: So I noticed that if I do this, when I print_r the baseURL in PHP, I only get `https://www.example.com/api?command=Get`

Comment: Why not build the url in proxy.php? Something like this may work: `$partnerName = $_GET['partnerName']; $authToken = $_GET['authToken']; $returnValueList = $_GET['returnValueList'];  $url = "https://www.example.com/api?command=Get&partnerName=".$partnerName."&authToken=".$authToken."&returnValueList=".$returnValueList;` 
You could also completely remove the url parameter in your ajax request: `url: "proxy.php"` or add also the base URL as a parameter in data, since you will build the full url in proxy.php

Answer (score 0):

The `data:` parameters are used as parameters to `proxy.php`, not the URL that's embedded in the `url=` parameter. So you'll need to create that first, then pass that as the `url` parameter in `data:`.

```js
function getReq(token) {
  console.log('get Req triggered in JS')
  let params = $.param({
    command: 'Get',
    partnerName: 'applicant',
    authToken: token,
    returnValueList: 'transactionList'
  });
  jQuery.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "proxy.php",
    data: {
      url: `https://www.example.com/api?${params}`
    },
    success: function(data) {
      console.log('get success', data)
    }
  })
}
```